# Generic mechanism to introduce default values for enums in Java

Tags: java

On our current project we are mapping some magic numbers from database (sigh, I know) to java enums like so:

```
public interface WithCode {
    Integer getCode();
}


public enum Role implements WithCode {
    OWNER(1),
    ADMIN(2),
    USER(3);

    @Getter Integer code;

    Role(Integer code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

We have handful of these, so we created an utility that finds appropriate enum by ID like so:

```
public interface EnumLookuper {
    static <T extends Enum<T> & WithCode> T ofCode(int code, Class<T> enumType) {
        return Arrays.stream(enumType.getEnumConstants())
                .filter(value -> Objects.equals(value.getCode(), code))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Unknown %s with code %d", enumType.getName(), code)));
    }
}
```

Our algorithm is perhaps a bit too aggressive - it *fails* on unknown values. Some other team members have added new magic numbers to DB and our project started to throw bunch of exceptions.

Now, I'd like to add `UNKNOWN` value to each enum (we have tens of those) and I was thinking of doing it a bit more generically, so we'd change the exception throwing line to something like:

```
.orElseGet(() -> defaultEnumValue())
```

Enforcing the defaults with an interface wouldn't work really, as we'd need to provide default value *for each* enum member. Any ideas of introducing elegant fallback/unknown values for each enum?

#### EDIT

Using a custom "unknown value interface" would force me to implement unknown value per enum member, for example:

```
interface UnknownValueProvider<T> {
  T unknown();
}

public enum Role implements WithCode, UnknownValueProvider<Role> {
    OWNER(1) {
    public Role unknown() {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are not able to return some new enum value, unless you add it to your enum class directly

Comment: maybe returning null / Optional will help

Comment: I was thinking of using `Optional` but I would need to change a *lot* of client code in that case

Comment: The best solution I see is to add this UNKNOWN field to each enum (the need of them could be anticipated in past). Trying to hack enums is not worth.

Comment: If you're further using the enum instances themselves then I think @AdamSkywalker is right. However if you use an abstraction, such as the `WithCode` interface or something else common, then you can simply provinde a custom `Unknown` implementation (somewhat similar to returning a [Null object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern#Java) instead of plain old `null`?!)

Comment: Apologies, I may have not been clear enough. I was referring to what you do from the point where you obtain your instance forward. If you really need to use the enum instance, or you can substitute it with a common interface, say `Command` for example. Your enum will implement both `WithCode & Command` and you'll also have an `UnknownCommand` class implementing the interface. Your *lookuper* will then return a `Command` which will either be an enum instance if it can find a match, or an *Unkown* one, and your code will simply call `command.execute()`.

Comment: What Java version are you using? Maybe a default implementation in a UnknownValueProvider interface could help?

Comment: @Morfic that sounds interesting, could you write a real answer with (ideally) compilable code?

Comment: I can certainly try but first I'd like to understand what you plan on doing with it after successfully mapping a number to an enum. Without having this context I can't say whether my suggestion adds any value or not

Comment: well the enum becomes a member of database-mapped entity and it is used when executing various business logic (eg. checking if the user making a http call has appropriate role to access a resource or so)

Comment: If it's used in entities which get persisted I'm afraid my solution would not work and @AdamSkywalker's suggestion makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

(Note: I am unfamiliar with portions of the code you have, namely most of the 2nd code block that gets the enum by ID. It seems overly complex/unintuitive, and it's different from all the code I've found that performs a similar function, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7996474/6083675). Is there a reason for it to be like that that I'm missing?)

---

I ran into a similar issue before, with some minor differences. In my case, I was using `valueOf()` to get the enum, but I wanted to make it case insensitive. So, inside my enum, I overloaded(?) `valueOf(anyCaseParam)` to return `valueOf(AnyCaseParam.toUpperCase())`.

## My Suggestion

You should add `UNKNOWN(-1)` to the list of enums (so that you have an enum to retrieve). I would then use something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5021344/6083675) has for a way to get the enum by its ID value.

From that answer, I modified the last bit of code to fit what you're asking:

```
public T getByID(int num) {

    // Old code: 
       //return map.get(num);


    int unknownEnum= -1;

    if(map.get(num)!=null)
      return map.get(num);
    else
      return map.get(unknownEnum);
}
```

If you wanted, you could even have another method that throws an exception instead of returning the `UNKNOWN` value.