# Comparing Numbers in string with Enum

Tags: java, enums, comparison

I'm using enumeration to define all my constant variables.

**Enum**

```
public enum ApplicationStatus {
        Initiated(1), PendingVerification(2), NotEligible(3), Approved(4), SoftDenial(
                5), Deferred(6), Saved(7), Cancelled(8), Approved_NoSSN(9), PendingVerification_NoSSN(
                10), Approved_Archived(11);

        private final int value;

        private ApplicationStatus(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int getStatusMasterId() {
            return value;
        }
    };
```

And I need to compare two integer values. What is the efficient way to compare the below integers?

**Comparing Integers:-**

```
public void applicationStatus(){
    String applicationStatus = null;
    String statusMasterId = "2";
    if(ApplicationStatus.PendingVerification.ordinal() == Integer.parseInt(statusMasterId)){
        applicationStatus = "Pending Verification";
    }
}
```

Suggestions Welcome!

Comment: probably a `switch case`

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use `getStatusMasterId` instead of `ordinal`?  I'd also consider having a method in `ApplicationStatus` which could take a `int` value and return an `ApplicationStatus`, but that's just me

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: you migh also want to add the `ApplicationStatus` message as `String` in your enum in order to not rewrite them all the time (if they never differ)

Comment: Try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996335/how-to-match-int-to-enum)

Comment: “What is the efficient way…” Why do you want it efficient? I very much doubt you need that.

Comment: @OleV.V. - Ordinal() returns false in this case. So I need to compare these two int values

Comment: Is the string always in the format `2`, or could it be for example `02` or `+2`?

Comment: It would be 0 to 10

Comment: A complete aside, `Approved_Archeived`, should that have been ‘archived’ or ‘achieved’?

Comment: Updated...... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a couple of suggestions. Feel free to discard if they are not right for you.

Since you say you need the ordinal number of the enum, you may go the other way:

```
    if (ApplicationStatus.values()[Integer.parseInt(statusMasterId)] == ApplicationStatus.PendingVerification) {
        // do your stuff
    }
```

Be aware that as in the question `Integer.parseInt(statusMasterId)` may throw a `NumberFormatException`.

Another suggestion, the compare method from Jay Smith’s answer may be taken a step further to accept a string argument:

```
public enum ApplicationStatus {
    Initiated(1), PendingVerification(2), NotEligible(3), Approved(4), 
    SoftDenial(5), Deferred(6), Saved(7), Cancelled(8), 
    Approved_NoSSN(9),PendingVerification_NoSSN(10), 
    Approved_Archeived(11);

    private final int value;
    // redundant representation of ordinal() as a string for comparison to other strings
    private final String ordinalAsString;

    private ApplicationStatus(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        ordinalAsString = String.valueOf(ordinal());
    }

    public int getStatusMasterId() {
        return value;
    }

    public boolean compare(String stringValue) {
        return this.ordinalAsString.equals(stringValue);
    }
}
```

There is no risk of a `NumberFormatException`, but you may consider the risk there is even worse: This will not recognize for example `"+2"` or `"02"` as representing the number 2. Whether you want to store the string value permanently in the enum object is questionable; if you are serious about wanting the comparison to be efficient, you do want to. Jay Smith’s code is using the `value`, I have changed it to using `ordinal()`.

Here’s the test!

```
    String statusMasterId = "2";
    if (ApplicationStatus.values()[Integer.parseInt(statusMasterId)] == ApplicationStatus.NotEligible) {
        System.out.println("Not eligible");
    }
    if (ApplicationStatus.NotEligible.compare(statusMasterId)) {
        System.out.println("Still not eligible using the compare() method");
    }
```

This prints

```
Not eligible
Still not eligible using the compare() method
```

This is because ordinals start from 0, so `NotEligible`, with a value of 3, has ordinal 2, it’s not the same thing.

Comment: I'm calling like this, but it is returning false - if(ApplicationStatus.Initiated.compare(statusMasterId)){
   applicationStatus = "Initiated";
   System.out.println(applicationStatus);
  }

Comment: Have u tested the compare() code... It is returning false

Comment: V.V - This works fine...But I'm trying to use the compare() in my if condition. That is returning false..And that is my concern

Comment: Thanks.It is working fine. I did a slight modification in this line.  ordinalAsString = String.valueOf(ordinal() + 1);

Comment: Very good. In that case I think you will want to name it `valueAsString` and assign `String.valueOf(value)` to it instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options two compare enums.

1. Use built in `compareTo` method of java enum. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#compareTo(E)
2. Create your own compare method within enum. Like:

   ```
   public enum ApplicationStatus {
       Initiated(1), PendingVerification(2), NotEligible(3), Approved(4), 
       SoftDenial(5), Deferred(6), Saved(7), Cancelled(8), 
       Approved_NoSSN(9),PendingVerification_NoSSN(10), 
       Approved_Archeived(11);

       private final int value;

       private ApplicationStatus(int value) {
           this.value = value;
       }

       public int getStatusMasterId() {
           return value;
       }
       public boolean compare(int value) {
           return this.value==value;
       }
   };
   ```

Comment: Very good information. I think you have been skipping the part about one of the numbers coming in a string. Maybe the asker can adjust for that himself/herself.